# How to download Eclipse's Source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After spending awhile (their wiki pages for CSV access are no longer valid, the password provided does not work) and their SVN repositories do not contain the code to Eclipse IDE or the core plugins. The same problem also appears to apply to their GIT repositories. In particular I am looking for the source code of this *core* plugin class (not even java specific):

plugin: org.eclipse.debug.core

class: org.eclipse.debug.core.model.IProcess

Finally, I also tried to import the plugin as a fragment with source directory. There is no packaged source file. My last option is to decompile the class files, but please tell me there is a better repository I can access with read only permission? Again their wiki is either outdated or not pointing me to the core code but other project repos.

Comment: What about [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.debug/core/3.6.0/org/eclipse/debug/core/model/IProcess.java?av=f)?

Comment: From deleted answer: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=1011083

Comment: @Keppil I think grepcode is the best solution for those who want to look at the code, as opposed to run it. So I think that is the best answer.

Comment: @Zombies: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it, the tricky part was there are so many repos just listed there on their git repo page (http://git.eclipse.org/c/), you kind of have to inspect each page, it is listed under the category "platform", as opposed to all the plugin ID's being listed in alphabetic order:

For org.eclipse.debug.core (where IProcess is), it is here:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.debug.git/tree/org.eclipse.debug.core

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your needs, [The Eclipse Common Build Infrastructure](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CBI) (CBI) might help.

The CBI project has converted Eclipse into a Tycho project which means you can [get all the sources and compile them into a working Eclipse build](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Platform_Build) with 2-3 commands.

Comment: I expounded upon your answer and included the detailed commands. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68569688/4561887.

Answer (score 6):

You can also check this fresh presentation by Lars Vogel :) [How to become an Eclipse committer in 20 minutes and fork the IDE](http://www.slideshare.net/LarsVogel/eclipse-committerin20minutes)

Comment: Is there no way to download Eclipse Kepler sourcecode with a browser in a single source.zip ?
I sit behind a proxy and even if git would allow it, don't want to download a zillion individual source files through the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to look at the code you can always use [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/).

For example, the Eclipse 4.2 version of the class you ask for is found here: [IProcess.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.debug/core/3.7.100/org/eclipse/debug/core/model/IProcess.java).

Answer (score 1):

Using [this link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Platform_Build#Building) (see the "Building" and "cloning platform source tree" sections) from [@Aaron Digulla here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15654653/4561887), this appears to be the way to download all Eclipse source code. I actually ran these instructions and they seem to work. I think this is everything.

```sh
# 1 .Clone the whole repo, including all submodules (sub-repos)
git clone -b master --recursive \
git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git
```

The clone process above took me about 30 minutes and downloaded 3.9 GB of stuff.

```sh
# 2. To update the git clone above, including all submodules
cd eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator
git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule update
```

That's it! That appears to be everything (I think). Here is what I see in the first level of the "eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator" folder I just cloned now:

```
eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator$ tree -L 1
.
├── cje-production
├── CONTRIBUTING
├── eclipse.jdt
├── eclipse.jdt.core
├── eclipse.jdt.core.binaries
├── eclipse.jdt.debug
├── eclipse.jdt.ui
├── eclipse.pde.build
├── eclipse.pde.ui
├── eclipse.platform
├── eclipse.platform.common
├── eclipse.platform.debug
├── eclipse-platform-parent
├── eclipse.platform.releng
├── eclipse.platform.releng.prereqs.sdk
├── eclipse.platform.releng.tychoeclipsebuilder
├── eclipse.platform.resources
├── eclipse.platform.runtime
├── eclipse-platform-sources
├── eclipse.platform.swt
├── eclipse.platform.swt.binaries
├── eclipse.platform.team
├── eclipse.platform.text
├── eclipse.platform.ua
├── eclipse.platform.ui
├── eclipse.platform.ui.tools
├── Jenkinsfile
├── JenkinsJobs
├── LICENSE
├── NOTICE
├── pom.xml
├── production
├── README.md
├── rt.equinox.binaries
├── rt.equinox.bundles
├── rt.equinox.framework
├── rt.equinox.p2
└── scripts

32 directories, 6 files
```

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Platform SDK Provisioning](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Platform_SDK_Provisioning) works, after  Eclipse Updater completed, it could run and debug eclipse, breakpoint also works.

For example, set breakpoint in `NewProjectAction.java` `NewProjectAction()` and `run()` method, when click `File > New > Project`, it pause at breakpoint.

[image]