# I am trying to locate eclipse's jar repositories for jsdt

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jsdt

To work on a project I am trying to locate a reliable repository where the jsdt core file is available.

Although the 'org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.core:3.14.0' was extremely easy to locate, I am not having the same look with the jsdt for my Gradle build. And I need some of the webtools.

When I download eclipse I can find the jar inside and I am able to locate the group and artifact ids. But not a repository to declare a dependency.

I found Jabylon and Alfresco, but they are from 2013, I also found one under other name from 2007. But I am trying to locate where they actually put those jars to be able to choose among current versions.

This is the bundle I am looking for: 
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core
It seems its group is org.eclipse.webtools.jsdt.bundles

any ideas?

Comment: Only one idea that is not helpful for you : your question is off topic here.

Comment: I am not trying to ask to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site". I know exacly what library to use and how to use it. however, eclipse's codes evolves a lot, and the main download page is not helpfull for maven/gradle. the group id has other names that I might have missed when looking into jcenter and others. I am looking for a way to declare that specific library in gradle.

Comment: (this is a missing dependency problem, I don't know how could this be of topic of fit in: "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site")

Comment: So a reliable repository is not an off site resource? Your question would be answered by a link, correct? Only a link, to be precise. Which exactly puts it in that off topic category.

Comment: ' I am trying to locate where they actually put those jars', not a recommendation for any link', in your view any android o modern java dependency issue would be of topic. My group id my be wrong too.

Comment: like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654475/how-to-download-eclipses-source-code -> the diff is that I need artifacts

Comment: Only some Eclipse plug-in JARs that are intended also be used outside of Eclipse in plain (non-OSGi) applications are published to Maven or Gradle repositories (e. g. Eclipse JGit). In the Eclipse world p2 instead of Maven/Gradle repositories are used (the artifacts you're looking for are [here](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon/) but cannot be accessed from Maven or Gradle).

Comment: that was what I was afraid of. it is sad cause it is an OSGI environment and the app is for an equinox based platform. that is why that lib would be perfect for it. well, if you could put it in an answer I will accept it. I was waiting for confirmation before building an uber.

Comment: @GhostCat The answer is not a link. Please do not close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @howlger Well, you need 5 votes for an off topic close to work out. Right now, I am there is only my vote. So probably this will stay open. And please ask yourself: would your answer "work" for future users without the links in it?

Comment: @GhostCat Which link are you talking about? See my answer, why there is no such link here as in most cases.

Comment: @howlger Like the one to the NEON update site? Which is kinda outdated already, because isn't Photon the latest thing?

Comment: @GhostCat That was regarding version 3.14.0. To make it clearer, I added _"e. g."_ and now refer to the new latest release update site instead. On Wednesday Photon will become outdated and 2018-09 will be the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only some Eclipse plug-in JARs that are intended also be used outside of Eclipse in plain (non-OSGi) applications are published by the Eclipse projects themselves to Maven or Gradle repositories (e. g. [Eclipse JGit](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit)).

In the Eclipse world, [**p2 repositories**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43895999/6505250) or simple folders containing the OSGi bundle JARs are used for so-called [target platforms](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/target.htm) **to built and run** a Java **OSGi application**.

The artifacts you're looking for are e. g. in the [latest simultaneous release update site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/) but cannot be accessed from Maven or Gradle.

Please note that some Eclipse plug-in JARs only work within an OSGi application (e. g. when a bundle activator class is used) or within an Eclipse-based application (e. g. when Eclipse extension points are used).

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I built a quick script to sort eclipse jars into a repository structure, so one can deploy if they can and have a server.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public final class DirToRepoStructure {

    private static final Pattern jarNamePattern = Pattern.compile( "(.*)_(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)\\.v?(\\d+)\\.jar" );

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

        Path root = Paths.get( args[ 0 ] );
        int rootNameCount = root.getNameCount( );

        String rootName = root.getFileName( )
                              .toString( );

        Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory( Paths.get( "." ), rootName );
        System.out.println( "using temporary directory: " + tempDir );

        Path achievePath = tempDir.getParent( )
                                  .resolve( rootName + ".zip" );
        System.out.println( "Archiving at: " + achievePath );

        DirectoryStream< Path > stream = Files.newDirectoryStream( root, "*.jar" );

        stream.forEach( jar -> {
            String fullName = jar.getFileName( )
                                 .toString( );

            System.out.println( fullName );
            Matcher matcher = jarNamePattern.matcher( fullName );

            if ( matcher.matches( ) ) {

                String jarName = matcher.group( 1 );

                String version = matcher.group( 2 );

                String snap = matcher.group( 3 );

                System.out.println( "reading: " + jarName + ", " + version );

                createJarStructure( tempDir, jar, jarName, version, snap );

            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "file name does not match regex" );
            }

        } );

        try ( FileSystem zipFs = getZipFs( achievePath ) ) {

            Files.walk( tempDir )
                 .skip( rootNameCount )
                 .forEach( source -> copyIntoZip( zipFs, source, rootNameCount ) );
        }
    }

    private static void copyIntoZip( FileSystem zipFs, Path source, int rootNameCount ) {

        try {
            Path zipRoot = zipFs.getPath( "/" );

            int tempRootNameCount = rootNameCount + 1;
            int sourceNameCount = source.getNameCount( );

            String newPathName = source.subpath( tempRootNameCount, sourceNameCount )
                                       .toString( );

            Path pathInZipFile = zipRoot.resolve( newPathName );
            Files.copy( source, pathInZipFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private static void createJarStructure( Path tempDir, Path jar, String jarName, String version, String snap ) {

        try {

            Path jarRoot = jar.getParent( )
                              .resolve( jarName )
                              .resolve( version + "-SNAPSHOT" );

            Path jarDirectory = Files.createDirectories( tempDir.resolve( jarRoot ) );

            String shortSnap = snap.substring( 0,8 );
            Path jarTarget = jarDirectory.resolve( jarName + "-" + version + "-"+ shortSnap + ".jar" ); Files.copy( jar, jarTarget );

        }
        catch ( IOException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private static FileSystem getZipFs( Path archivePath ) throws IOException {

        Map< String, String > env = new HashMap<>( );
        env.put( "create", "true" );
        env.put( "encoding", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString( ) );

        System.out.println( archivePath );
        URI uri = URI.create( "jar:file:" + archivePath.toAbsolutePath( ) );
        return FileSystems.newFileSystem( uri, env );

    }
}
```